# В чём разница между "оценка" и "оценивание"?

Tags: стилистика, терминология, лингвистика

В электроэнергетике есть термин, в употреблении которого никак не удаётся прийти к консенсусу: часть энергетиков говорит "оценка состояния", часть - "оценивание состояния". Есть ли какая-то разница с лингвистической точки зрения? Какое слово в каком случае следует употреблять?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Гугле при поиске закавыченных терминов "[оценивание состояния](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&biw=1274&bih=893&ei=8n8XW6GFE8TYgAaAubfoCw&q=%22%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%22+%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8D%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0&oq=%22%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%22+%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8D%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0&gs_l=psy-ab.3...122365.124910.0.135854.2.2.0.0.0.0.154.280.0j2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.1AAjB4HyO6Y)" и "[оценка состояния](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&biw=1274&bih=893&ei=1H8XW-z0NcytgAbS1qKQAg&q=%22%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%22+%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8D%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0&oq=%22%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%22+%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8D%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0&gs_l=psy-ab.3...116288.118717.0.119250.2.2.0.0.0.0.154.297.0j2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.9zuU0NTcB28)" в сочетании со словом "электроэнергетика" результатов по первому запросу примерно в 27 раз меньше, чем по второму (более 2000 против более 54 000)

В [предложении](http://isem.irk.ru/publications/503/)

> Рассматривается задача **оценивания** состояния электроэнергетических
>   систем (ЭЭС) по текущим значениям наблюдаемых параметров этих систем.
>   Оценивание состояния электроэнергетической системы: алгоритмы и примеры решения линеаризованных задач

<sup>*Гурина Л.А., Зоркальцев В.И., Колосок И.Н., Коркина Е.С., Мокрый И.В. "Оценивание состояния электроэнергетической системы: алгоритмы и примеры решения линеаризованных задач", ИСЭМ СО РАН ISBN: 978-5-93908-148-1, 2016*</sup>

на мой взгляд можно применить и слово "**оценка**", так как из контекста (фраза: *задача оценивания*) уже понятно, что речь идёт о *действии*.

Соглашаясь с другими ответами, считаю, что "**оценка**" менее специфично, в то время как "**оценивание**" более уместно в контекстах, где необходимо подчеркнуть именно значение *действия*. Кроме того,  стилистически на мой вкус "**оценивание**" звучит несколько громоздко и напоминает канцелярит,  потому я бы воздержался от его применения без нужды.

Answer (score 3):

И "оценка", и "оценивание" могут означать действие, процесс; "оценка", кроме того, может означать итог, результат.

Вероятнее всего, речь о личных предпочтениях говорящих, одни из которых предпочитают проводить это различие (или переняли речевой оборот у предпочитавших это различие), для других же это не столь важно. Или даже случайность выбора.

Ведь этого нет в нормативных документах?

Answer (score 2):

**Оценивание** (чего-либо) может означать *только* **действие** (завершающееся *оценкой*), поэтому слово может употребляться *вне контекста*.

**Оценка** (чего-либо) может иметь как смысл **действия оценивания**, так и смысл **результата оценивания** (например, количественного). Поэтому для распознания значения слова *обязателен контекст*.

Answer (score 1):

Существительное «оценка» гораздо многозначнее, чем «оценивание». Вот основные значения:

> ОЦЕ́НКА, оценки, жен.
>   1. только ед. Действие по гл. оценить-оценивать. Произвести оценку имущества.

В данном значении оно синонимично существительному « оценивание».

> 2. Назначенная или определенная кем-нибудь стоимость, цена. Низкая оценка. Высокая оценка.
> 3. Мнение, суждение, высказанное о качествах кого-чего-нибудь. Правильная оценка чьих-нибудь поступков. Дать настоящую оценку кому-чему-нибудь.

2-3 значения являются результатом первого.

> 4. Школьный балл, отметка.

Вам надо учитывать, идет ли речь о процессе (**оценивание/оценка**) или о результате(**оценка**)